# Algorithm to rearrange lines as diameter of circle

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to re-arrange columns in an array as being diameters of a circle. Assuming that each column is at a correponding angle, e.g. 0,1, ... 180 degrees.

The idea is to implement the "re-gridding step" of the inverse Radon transform:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform#/media/File:Radon_transform_via_Fourier_transform.png

I don't think it is just polar to cartesian /cart 2 pol conversion ...

Comment: Linking to a picture alone does not help a lot for a specific numerical method for such a sophisticated and/or domain specific mathematical transform.  The wiki article at the linked image does not really discuss the algorithmic details of the transform or its inverse.  Do you have any links that can better explain this?  I found this article (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3480277/ )is that the specific algorithm you are looking to implement?

Comment: Hmmm, well that article is pretty dense, not a lot of help either...